# I want to link one column from one table to same column name with another table in mysql so that i am able to carryout the add,update,delete opeations

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table

1: Roll_no Name Address Branch
 2: Roll_no Branch Name Percentage Marks

Is it possible in database that when i will add/update/Delete the data from one table it automatically do the operation on another with out front end programming...

Comment: Look into the documentation on triggers:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gordan said the triggers are the best way to do this.
Follow the below steps to achieve your requirement,

1. Create Trigger using the below query,

   CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   AFTER INSERT
      ON 'User' FOR EACH ROW
   Insert into 'UserCreatedTime' values(NOW())

What it meant, After inserting the values into 'User' table insert query for 'UserCreatedTime' table will be triggered automatically.

Please check the youtube video for more details,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKDqZCkBRZ8